# Find the tr having maximum number of th

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
   <th colspan="2" rowspan="1">Col 1</th>
   <th  colspan="2" rowspan="1">Col 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 3</th>
   <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 4</th>
   <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 5</th>
   <th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Col 6</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to find the tr which having greater number of 'th'. Please suggest an answer for me

Answer (score 1):

This is real basic but try something like this:

```
var rowWithHightestChildCount,
    currentHighestRowCount = 0;

$("thead>tr").each(function(){
    var childCount = $(this).children().length;

    if(childCount > currentHighestRowCount){
        currentHighestRowCount = childCount;
        rowWithHightestChildCount = $(this);
    }
})

console.log("Row", rowWithHightestChildCount);
console.log("Row Count", currentHighestRowCount);
```

The var **rowWithHightestChildCount** will contain the element with the greater number of **th** elements